# Playing preloaded MP4

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

I'm trying to achieve seamless looping of an MP4 (or M4A to be more specific) sound. The usual method of loading, playing to the end, and then seeking to position zero causes a small delay (less than a second) before the second playback begins.

So now I'm trying to preload the sound data and then use `NetStream.appendBytes()` to append the whole sound data at the end of the original sound, expecting the sound to repeat once. But first, I want to be able to play the sound just once using the `appendBytes()` method. Here is the code I wrote that doesn't give any errors but doesn't play a sound either:

```
var data:ByteArray = new SoundData; // SoundData class contains the embedded M4A file data
var connection: NetConnection = new NetConnection();
connection.connect(null);
var stream: NetStream = new NetStream(connection);
stream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatus);
stream.client = {};

function onNetStatus(event:NetStatusEvent): void {
    trace(event.info.code, stream.time, stream.bytesLoaded, stream.bytesTotal);
}

stream.play(null);
stream.appendBytesAction(NetStreamAppendBytesAction.RESET_BEGIN);
stream.appendBytes(data);
```

Am I using `appendBytes()` correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a hack for achieving apparent seamless looping: loading two sound files through NetStream, playing one, and 100ms before its end, starting to play the other.

Comment: Another hack that does not require two files is to simply have a count of total time and elapsed/playing time then in an `enterFrame` event when the two `Numbers` match (notice: not `int`) you can then have an `IF` statement to cause a seek to 0... Better still how do you check if only 100ms left? can that check not seek to 0 rather than loading a second file etc?

Comment: Another that I've used for sound and video objects is to simply do a hitTest on my interface's playbar width, when it touches hitTarget (placed at required X pos in the path of the play bar) it will trigger seek to 0. The target can be transparent to the eye or visible and used as marker of "loop from here"

Comment: Seeking causes a slight delay before the sound resumes.